# AngularJS ng-click and ng-view not responding

Tags: angularjs

I am using ng-show and ng-click to show / hide 2 divs based on the user click of one of the app menu as shown below. The problem I am facing is that on clicking on the link to display the dashboard div nothing is shown, instead the other div (div2) is always shown. Can someone please check my code and let me know what exactly I am doing wrong here? Thanks

index

```
<div id="header" ng-controller="MenuController">
        <ul >
          <li>
            <a href="#/">Main</a>
          </li>
          <li>
               <a href ng-hide="userLogged == 1">Login</a>
               <a href ng-click="switchDashboard()" ng-show="userLogged > 1">Dashboard</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
</div>   
<div>
  <div ng-controller="MenuController">

    <div id="dashboard" ng-show="showUserPanel">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/">Menu item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Menu item 2</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="div2" ng-hide="showUserPanel">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/">Reg item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Reg item 2</a></li>
            </ul>          
    </div>

    <div ng-view></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

MenuController:

```
        $scope.showUserPanel = false;

        $scope.switchDashboard = function(){
            $scope.showUserPanel = !$scope.showUserPanel;
        };
```

I have also tried changing the index to have only one instance for MenuController, but I still have as shown below the same problem

```
<div id="header" ng-controller="MenuController">
        <ul >
          <li>
            <a href="#/">Main</a>
          </li>
          <li>
               <a href ng-hide="userLogged == 1">Login</a>
               <a href ng-click="switchDashboard()" ng-show="userLogged > 1">Dashboard</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

    <div id="dashboard" ng-show="showUserPanel">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/">Menu item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Menu item 2</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="div2" ng-hide="showUserPanel">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/">Reg item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="/">Reg item 2</a></li>
            </ul>          
    </div>

</div>   
<div>
  <div ng-controller="MenuController">

    <div ng-view></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 different instances of your controller and they will function independently of each other, see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k4YH6/

HTML:

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <button type="button" ng-click="increment()">Ctrl instance 1: {{value}}</button>
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <button type="button" ng-click="increment()">Ctrl instance 2: {{value}}</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.value = 1;
    $scope.increment = function () {
        $scope.value++;
    };
}
```

More related fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jph4n/

Comment: I've tried having just one instance, moving the 2 divs under the div of header, but still it didn't work...

Comment: I added a more related fiddle, which I believe has the functionality you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the switchDashoard() function.

```
ng-click="showUserPanel = !showUserPanel"
ng-show="showUserPanel"
```

`showUserPanel = !showUserPanel` Will toggle the values for ng-show/ng-hide.

Comment: There is no real difference here between both approaches, but anyway I've tried ng-click using your approach before and still it didn't work